# What is wrong with my hyperlink?

Tags: php

```
$var = '<a href="http://amazon.com/dp/$v">http://amazon.com/dp/' . $v.'</a>';
```

In my address bar, I don't see the $v value to be passed. I have tried putting it in quotes ETC and it still does not show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using single quotes it is a literal string. Change it to:

```
$var = '<a href="http://amazon.com/dp/'.$v.'">http://amazon.com/dp/'.$v.'</a>';
```

Or

```
$var = "<a href=\"http://amazon.com/dp/$v\">http://amazon.com/dp/$v</a>";
```

Comment: I would suggest using the first version as it is much more readable and consistent with how other languages work. Using the second one also involves the problem of escaping special characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = '<a href="http://amazon.com/dp/' . $v . '">http://amazon.com/dp/' . $v.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes in order to replace $variables in a "string".

Or break it and concatenate with . (dots)

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not parse the variable inside a string unless the string is wrapped in double quotes/ Change your code to:

```
$var = "<a href='http://amazon.com/dp/$v'>http://amazon.com/dp/".$v."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you probably want to `urlencode()` the `$v` in the `href` attribute and `htmlentities()` the `$v` in the tag body, this is probably the best approach to what you are trying to accomplish:

```
$var = sprintf(
  '<a href="http://amazon.com/dp/%s">%s</a>',
    urlencode($v),
    htmlentities($v)
);
```